# How to change SensorTag name?

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, texas-instruments

I am looking for a way to change SensorTag name. Apparently TI App Store application capable to do so as it changes name of SensorTag after first connect so it is become "TI BLE Sensor Tag".

Comment: Btw could someone explain why I got -2 points for this question? Is the fact that someone do not understand a question worth down-voting? I do not think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TI App doesn't *change* the name of the sensor tag.

Names with BLE work a bit differently than what you might expect. Here is a simplified version of what's going on:

1. First, the sensor tag sends a packet to the iPhone indicating that it is a sensor tag. This packet does not contain any name, so the iPhone cannot display a name here.
2. Sometimes, the iPhone immediately replies with a question asking the tag for additional information. This information does not provide much space (only a few bytes), but some vendors put in a shortened name of the device in there. In this case, iPhone will display this shortened name.
3. Only after connecting to the tag, iPhone can examine the *Device Name* characteristic of the sensor tag and knows the final name of the device. From here on, iPhone will display this full name.

iOS will cache the last known name. So, if you were once connected and the final name has been retrieved from the *Device Name* characteristic, iOS will display this name even while not connected to the sensor tag. This may be the reason why you are thinking that the app somehow changes the name of the sensor tag.

Comment: It explains everything about current behavior. Is there a way to change value returned by Device Name characteristic? I would like to provide some meaningful information about particular device rather than "sensortag" or cryptic UDIDs. Anyway I will confirm this answer as correct one, I just one two get some additional information that could be helpful for my work. Thanks!

Comment: CoreBluetooth doesn't allow writing of the device name. Also, the CBPeripheral's identifier property is not globally unique - if you use an other iPhone, a different identifier will be generated. What you could do is to add a UUID <-> Friendly Name mapping in your app and only display the friendly name to the user. As long as the user will not switch iPhones, this mapping should be ok - otherwise, they'll have to name the device again.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to modify the firmware of the SensorTag to change the name. TI makes the BLE stack available for free and you can upload the new firmware over the air from the SensorTag app.